# Does possible upgrade Subclipse to 1.8 without lost of work?

Tags: java, eclipse, subclipse

I would like to upgrade Subclipse for Eclipse from 1.6 to 1.8. But I have to do a lot of work:
deinstall 1.6, install 1.8 and what the biggest problem - need delete all .svn folder!
But I have near 50 modified files - so I need to wait to finish my work or lost all changes.
Is a way to resolve all these problems? Thanks.

Comment: You need to delete your .svn folders to upgrade Subclipse? That doesn't sound right...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about the install process, but even if you DO delete your .svn files, you won't loose your work!

When you checkout from SVN, the process is smart enough not to override the files that are different from what you have locally, so you shouldn't have a problem there. When you synchronize, it'll detect the files as different from what's committed and will ask you to commit/merge/solve conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

Just uninstall all parts of Subclipse 1.6, and install Subclipse 1.8. The .svn files will be updated, and no work will be lost.

Comment: And after that, if you get the "Working copy is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)" error, click on Team -> Upgrade